# dismiss dialog when back to activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-dialog

I followed the [Android Developer document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) to created a notification

When a notification is shown on the top bar, I click on that notification and my activity is opened. In onCreate() of MyActivity, I get the intent set by notification, and show a dialog.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //get extras from intent from notification component
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras != null){
             showDialog();
        }
   }

   private void showDialog(){
      ...
      //There is a "open" button on the dialog, which opens browswer
      openButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
            //I dismiss the dialog
           dismissDialog();

            //Then I open the browser
           Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myUrl));
           startActivity(browserIntent);

       }
    });
   }

}
```

There is a "open" button on the shown dialog, when click on that button, the browser is opened. Everything works fine here.

If now press the physical back button, browser disappear, MyActivity is shown again. **however**, the `onCreate()` is called again (sometimes), in which the `Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();` get the same intent again, and the dialog is shown again.

How to make sure after browser has opened for the dialog, when press physical back button, the dialog is not shown again?

Comment: Add flag into intent.

Comment: define `sometimes`? (use startActivityForResult to detect the fact that you are coming back from the browser)

Comment: @Pankaj , I added flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, it doesn't help.

Comment: @njzk2, it is back from the browser

Answer (score 0):

Try like this way:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myUrl));
finish();         
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

**Another way** is by taking static boolean variable/prefrence:

```
static boolean isNotify=false;
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(extras != null)
        {
             isNotify= true;
        }
```

Put this code in your onResume() method:

```
    if(isNotify)
    {
         isNotify=false;
         showDialog();
    }
```

Comment: if call finish() my activity would be destroyed. I still need my activity be shown when back from browser.